# How to remove empty links (empty tags containing an href=“x”) in HTML source?

Tags: javascript, html

I have identified empty links on a page, and i need to remove this on the page using javascript. Texts are in anchor tags

Comment: What do you mean by *remove links*? Remove the `href` attribute? Empty the text content? Remove the `<a>` element entirely?

Comment: ^That and also, show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Remove the a element by leave the text content behind?

Comment: remove links meaning when I wave (using wave tool) the particular page, there will no empty link errors left

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

```
var linkDescription = `<a href="">Lorem Ipsum without href</a> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<a href="https://www.lipsum.com/"> Lorem Ipsum with href </a> has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.`;
var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(let i=0; i< allLinks.length; i++) {
  if (allLinks[i].baseURI == allLinks[i].href) {
     linkDescription= linkDescription.split(allLinks[i].outerHTML).join(allLinks[i].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

check here [stackBlitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1wcbgb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

What I am understanding is that you want to remove `<a>` tags with empty `innerHTML` from your page (i.e. links with no text to click on).

If this is the case, then this should work:

```js
//list of all anchor elements in your HTML DOM
onload = function() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var anchor = anchors[i];
    if(anchor.innerHTML == "") {
      anchor.parentNode.removeChild(anchor); //removes the anchor
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x"></a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below if you want to delete element if its href is not a valid url.

```
let elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
    let href = element.href
    if(!ValidURL(href))
     element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
});


function ValidURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\/\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\d]([a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])*)\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\:\d+)?(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\?[;&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\#[-a-z\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locater
  if(!pattern.test(str)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid URL.");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Regexp from [Devshed](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/regexp-match-url-pattern-493764.html):

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you have this structure

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = '';
}
```

```html
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
```

Comment: This will set the the `href` of every anchor on the page to empty, not just the ones with `href="x"`. But even if it did only affect those, it is not clear from the question that this is what OP wants.

Comment: I didn't vote you down but please rethink your answer. Your solution will blank all the links on a page. Secondly, I think the question is how to remove the whole `<a>` when the `href` attribute is  "x" or "". Good luck and welcome on SO